# Get data from parsed textResponse in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have respond from a server and with my code I get the result from the picture:

[image: My Console]

This is my code:

```js
    $(function() {
      $('#register-form').submit(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
                 
          var url = 'Link deleted';
          // Validate data
          // TODO
          
          var data = {
              nick: $("#register-form #name").val(),
              password: $("#register-form #password").val(),
              email:  $("#register-form #email").val(),
              countryIso: $("#register-form #country option:selected").val()
          };
          
          console.log($.param(data));
          
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $.param(data, true),
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              'Accept': 'application/vnd.api+json'
            }
          }).done(function(data) {
            console.log( "Uspjesno poslato, odgovor od servera vracen u vidu: ", data);
                // Uradi nesto sa ovim podacima
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, exception) {
          console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
             var error = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
             console.log(error);
             
          
        }).always(function() {
          console.log( "Complete" );
          
        });
      });
    });
```

I want to get only text from detail, but I don't know how to access this text.
I tried:

```js
    var test = "error.errors[0].detail";
    console.log(test);
```

But it's not working.. Can someone help me with this please? :)

Comment: Please format your question to make it readable... what do you want and what is not working.

Comment: `test` is a string , Try `console.log(error.errors[0].detail);` with no quotes

Comment: @charlietfl it works! Thank you so much. :)
https://prnt.sc/tfvrk7

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved in the comment of @charlietfl above.

```
console.log(error.errors[0].detail);
```